# Create floor for a top down 3d game

Tags: texturing, export, faces, performance

Dear blender community,

I am a beginner in 3D animation and I am planning to make a 3D top down perspective game. 
I want to create the game 3D assets in blender and export it to use in an external game engine.
The game should have a rather big area with plain ground. On the ground are a lot of things like streets with lots of complicated street routes etc.

What is the most common way to do this? Just having a plane as the ground in blender and adding the streets and all other floor structures via textures?
Or creating the streets and all other structures in blender directly with 2D faces and adding more specific textures to those faces.

Comment: If you want to interact with the streets and floor structures you should make a separate objects for it.  If its just for the aesthetics you can just use textures. It depends on what you wanna do with it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I don't need to interact with it. So using just textures has the better performance? Should I use many smaller planes with parts of the texture or one big texture?

Comment: This is a complex and broad topic that depends on what type of game you are doing. There's no certain one way to do a 3D game environment.